# Why am I getting spikes in the values of the loss function during training?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, keras, objective-functions

I trained a neural network on the [UNSW-NB15 dataset](https://www.unsw.adfa.edu.au/unsw-canberra-cyber/cybersecurity/ADFA-NB15-Datasets/), but, during training, I am getting spikes in the loss function. The algorithms see part of this UNSW dataset a single time. The loss function is plotted after every batch.

[image]

For other datasets, I don't experience this problem.  I've tried different optimizers and loss functions, but this problem remains with this dataset.

I'm using the `fit_generator()` function from Keras. Is there anyone experience this problem using Keras with this function?

Answer (score 1):

The spikes could be caused by many reasons: insufficient model capacity, incorrect label, buggy input parsing, ... Finding out the culprit requires some detective work. For instance, you could apply the learned model to the whole train set and manually examine the datapoints which result in the highest loss. Alternatively, you could compare the learning outcomes of different models (both weaker and stronger).

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Ng explains with great details in [Deep Learning Course](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/deep-neural-network/understanding-mini-batch-gradient-descent-lBXu8) appears in the image below.
He also focuses on some corners can cause this problem :

1. some mislabeled examples in the dataset.
2. the size of your mini batch or change it with GD.

[image]

Comment: This is not the same as this case, the mean of spikes in Andrew Ng's picture is pretty much a smooth curve, whereas the mean in OP's graph it is irregular.